# Find derivate of y with respect to v (hyperbolic functions)

Tags: derivatives, hyperbolic-functions

Need to find derivative of $ y = \ln \operatorname{cosh}v - \frac 1 2 \operatorname{tanh}^2 v $

Any help would be appreciated. The answer is $ \operatorname{tanh}^3v $ but I have no clue how to get that.

I currently have $ \frac {1}{-\operatorname{sinh}v} - \frac 12 (2 \operatorname{tanh}v) * \operatorname{sech}^2v $ but I don't know how to get from there or if that's even correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you almost had it. But $$\frac{d}{dv}\left(\log \cosh (v)\right)=\tanh(v)$$  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dv}\left(\log \cosh (v)-\frac12 \tanh^2(v)\right)&=\tanh (v)-\tanh (v)\, \text{sech}^2 (v)\\\\
&=\tanh(v)(1-\text{sech}^2(v))\\\\
&=\tanh^3(v)
\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you get that the log of coshv = tanhv?? Is there some sort of law/identity/definition I am missing?

Comment: Sure.  The chain rule.  $\frac{d\log x}{dx}=1/x$ and $\frac{d \cosh x}{dx}=\sinh x$.

Comment: Which would then make it $ \frac {1}{-sinhx} $ just like I put. Like, how did you get that to become tanhv?

Comment: $\frac{d\log(\cosh v)}{dv}=\frac{d\log(\cosh v)}{d\cosh v}\times\frac{d\cosh v}{dv}=\frac{1}{\cosh v}\times \sinh v=\tanh v$

Comment: You just blew me mind :O Thank you so much for being patient with me :)

Comment: 2 more small things. Wouldn't it be a negative tanhv since the derivative is -sinhv? And how does the $ tanhvsech^2 $ turn into $ 1 - sech^2 v $

Comment: I found the second part of my question, but I still don't know how you get a positive tabh v not a negative

Comment: The derivative of $\cosh x$ is $+\sinh x$.  We can see this as follows:  $\frac{d \cosh x }{dx}=\frac{d\left(\frac12(e^x+e^{-x})\right)}{dx}=\frac12(e^x-e^{-x})=\sinh x$.